# How can I GROUP BY in conjunction with a JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to take values from a column in one table and combine them with the max across multiple columns in another table where the first table's value appears multiple times as a foreign key. I also need to limit the number of occurrences to 1 in what the SELECT returns.

My (simplified) tables look something like the following:

```
Names:
+--+------+
|PK|  name|
+--+------+
| 1|  Fred|
| 2|   Bob|
| 3|George|
+--+------+
Values:
+--+----+----+----+--+
|PK|val1|val2|val3|FK|
+--+----+----+----+--+
| 1|   1|   2|   5| 2|
| 2|   2|   0|   2| 1|
| 3|   1|   1|NULL| 1|
| 4|   7|   0|NULL| 2|
| 5|   0|   3|   3| 3|
| 6|   5|   2|   2| 3|
| 7|   6|   3|   0| 1|
| 8|   1|   2|   5| 3|
| 9|   0|   2|NULL| 2|
+--+----+----+----+--+
```

My current request is:

```sql
SELECT Name.name, GREATEST(Vals.val1, COALESCE(val2, 0), COALESCE(val3, 0))
    FROM Name INNER JOIN (Vals) ON Name.PK = Vals.FK;
```

The intention is to get the max value that ever occurs for each name. The result should look something like the following:
Maxes:

```
+------+---+
|  name|max|
+------+---+
|  Fred|  6|
|   Bob|  7|
|George|  5|
+------+---+
```

But currently what I'm seeing is:

```
+------+---+
|  name|max|
+------+---+
|  Fred|  2|
|  Fred|  1|
|  Fred|  6|
|   Bob|  5|
|   Bob|  7|
|   Bob|  2|
|George|  3|
|George|  5|
|George|  5|
+------+---+
```

Where I get the average for each occurrence of the name key. I'm not sure whether I need a 'WHERE' or 'GROUP BY' to solve this but each time I've attempted either, I'm getting errors. For example:

```sql
SELECT Name.name, GREATEST(Vals.val1, COALESCE(val2, 0), COALESCE(val3, 0))
    FROM Name INNER JOIN (Vals) ON Name.PK = Vals.FK GROUP BY Name.name;

SELECT Name.name, GREATEST(Vals.val1, COALESCE(val2, 0), COALESCE(val3, 0)) WHERE Vals.FK = Name.PK
    FROM Name INNER JOIN (Vals) ON Name.PK = Vals.FK;
```

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design. Any time you find yourself with enumerated column names (above, say, 2), alarm bells should start ringing. That said, `MAX(GREATEST...) ... GROUP BY` should solve your problem

Comment: The values correspond to discrete events that each need to be tracked (think values from each time each person conducts a science experiment) due to the nature of the assignment. As per the instructions, each value must be recorded in the same table and in the manner shown above. I'm open to hear how the design can be improved for my own knowledge, but unfortunately it's unavoidable here.

Comment: Typically, you would split the values table in two. Let's pretend it's a table of orders. So one table would hold the order_id and the customer_id, and the other would hold the details of what was ordered, maybe order_id,item_id,quantity. See? Each item gets its own row; NOT its own column.

Comment: Incidentally, I doubt you need COALESCE here.

Comment: Yeah, that's sort of where I figured it would go in a more practical scenario. Is there an alternative to COALESCE for ignoring NULLs in a situation like this? prior to those, The GREATEST was returning a NULL on any row where they were present. Datatype is TINYINT UNSIGNED if that helps.

Comment: Well then I'm mistaken, and you do need the COALESCE - another argument in favour of fixing the data model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducing multiple rows into single value per group is achieved by aggregate functions, e.g. [MAX](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-max-function/):

```
SELECT Name.name,
       MAX(GREATEST(Vals.val1, COALESCE(val2, 0), COALESCE(val3, 0))) max
  FROM Name
  INNER JOIN (Vals) ON Name.PK = Vals.FK
  GROUP BY Name.name;
```

Comment: Doing this results in an ERROR 1140 (42000): In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'database.Name.name'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: what do you mean `without GROUP BY` - did you list all columns from `SELECT` that are outside of `MAX` also in the `GROUP BY`? in your example there is only 1 such column, "Name.name", but in your actual query there might be more...

Comment: I took a closer look and had just mistyped the correction, works great now. Thanks so much!